# How to install ImageMagick on Pterodactyl panel

Tags: python, imagemagick, imagick

I'm running on a Ubuntu 22.04 VM. I have pterodactyl running on it. I have a Python script on the panel, which generates videos by concatenating some videos. It needs ImageMagick for Text. I installed ImageMagick using "sudo apt install imagemagick". It still said ImageMagick not found, so I transferred the installed files from the folder it was installed to inside the PT server files. It finds ImageMagick now but says this

```
Error: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:
/home/container/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Magick/bin/convert: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've also tried directly installing ImageMagick in the server files, instead of just transferring the downloaded files. BUT STILL, the same error shows up

Comment: Please provide enough Python code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.